# How to Insert mutiple values in column chart?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, charts

How to add multiple column as in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd489240(v%3Dvs.100)) to following snippet?

```
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Chart Title")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] {  "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
        .Write();
}
```

I searched and tryed some answers, but cant find the right one. It is a very basic implementation, so it doesnt need a fancy chart creators.

Thank you.

P.S. this question was probably made before (it looks so easy), but I couldnt find it in stackoverflow :-/

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but seems that you want to add multiple series in a chart. If it's your problem, you can add another `AddSeries` method with same `xValue` & `yValues` set from another collection (array or `List`)

Comment: Exactly.... Please make an answer (with the following code if you wish) as an example for possible future searches, so I can accept it as correct answer.

I will post an answer if you dont with one or two details for future searches... thanks for your time!

Comment: @{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 250, height: 250, theme: ChartTheme.Vanilla)
        .AddTitle("Chart Title")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "ChartTitle",
            chartType: "column", //"Pie"
            xValue: new[] { "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "5", "6", "4", "5" }
           )
           .AddSeries(
            xValue: new[] { "Col12", "Col23", "Col32", "Col44", "Co2l5" },
            yValues: new[] { "1", "5", "6", "4", "5" })
           .Write();
}